# Get image to 100% width with text overlay

Tags: html, css

What I am trying is to get a section that has a height of 450px and in the background should be a picture with sort of a text-box on top of it.

I just can not make a shift to the picture with using margins. I would like it to be more centered, but whatever I use, it does not work. Also it does not fill 100% even if I set width to 100% in any class.

```css
.text-and-image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 450px;
  display: flex;
  overflow:hidden;
  object-fit: cover;
  background: steelblue;

  /* background: rgb(156, 156, 156); */
}


.text-and-image-box{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.text-and-image-image{
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 600px;
  height: auto;
  background: yellow;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.text-and-image-box2{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 55%;
  width: 35%;
  padding: 2%;
  height: auto;
  background: white;
}

.text-and-image-caption{
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  background: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-style: oblique;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="Website">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./fragebeispiel.css">
    <title>AMH Solingen</title>
  </head>

  <body>



<!-- Text neben Bild -->
<div class="text-and-image">

  <div class="text-and-image-box">
    <img class="text-with-image-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513135065346-a098a63a71ee?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1049&q=80">
  </div>

  <div class="text-and-image-box2">
    <p class="text-and-image-caption">Ein schlechtes Messer fährt leichter in die Hand als ins Brot.</p>
    <p class="text-and-image-text">Jeder Hobby- oder Profikoch braucht gutes Werkzeug. Nur damit macht es Spaß und ist sicher. Solinger Küchenmesser und Stahlwaren bestechen schon seit Jahrhunderten durch ausgezeichnete Qualität, hohe Langlebigkeit und innovative Lösungen. Das merkt man und hat seinen Weg schon in Millionen von Küchen in aller Welt gefunden. Unser Statement: </p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have a CSS rule `.text-and-image-image` that is not applied because the class in the HTML is `text-with-image-image`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this is what you are trying to achieve. From what I understood you want to centre the box in the middle of the image.

The logic I used was calculating the left position of `.text-and-image-box2` (100% of parent - own width/2)

**Edit:** I would also consider going over your css and cleaning it up a little. There is a lot of "unnecessary noise" that can be removed such as object-fit 3xtimes

```css
.text-and-image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 450px;
  display: flex;
  overflow:hidden;
  object-fit: cover;
  background: steelblue;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  /* background: rgb(156, 156, 156); */
}


.text-and-image-box{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.text-and-image-image{
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 600px;
  height: auto;
  background: yellow;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.text-and-image-box2{
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(100% - 17,5%);
  width: 35%;
  padding: 2%;
  height: auto;
  background: white;
}

.text-and-image-caption{
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  background: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-style: oblique;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="Website">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./fragebeispiel.css">
    <title>AMH Solingen</title>
  </head>

  <body>



<!-- Text neben Bild -->
<div class="text-and-image">

  <div class="text-and-image-box">
    <img class="text-with-image-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513135065346-a098a63a71ee?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1049&q=80">
  </div>

  <div class="text-and-image-box2">
    <p class="text-and-image-caption">Ein schlechtes Messer fährt leichter in die Hand als ins Brot.</p>
    <p class="text-and-image-text">Jeder Hobby- oder Profikoch braucht gutes Werkzeug. Nur damit macht es Spaß und ist sicher. Solinger Küchenmesser und Stahlwaren bestechen schon seit Jahrhunderten durch ausgezeichnete Qualität, hohe Langlebigkeit und innovative Lösungen. Das merkt man und hat seinen Weg schon in Millionen von Küchen in aller Welt gefunden. Unser Statement: </p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does a child can only get 100% width of its parent or can it still get 100% of the entire page? Also thanks for highlighting the redundant object-fits

Comment: Of course, advice: go to codepen and create a div (parentDiv) and inside that div another one (childDiv). Give the parent div and height and width and bg color. To your child, give position absolute and a few more pixels in width that its parent. Result: overflows the parent

Comment: And as long as I do not use an absolute position but let's say a relative position. Will the childDiv stay within the parentDiv?

Comment: I told you how to check the absolute positioning case in codePen. Do the same for all the cases you are in doubt ;) by doing it you will understand it better